# Is there a way to show JavaScript array brackets and the content of an object when using a browser's Developer's Tools?

Tags: browser, javascript

When I display an array in the F12 Dev Tools to try to figure out what is going on in a JavaScript program, I don't get the brackets. Normally, this wouldn't be a problem. But, I am currently working on a project with multidimensional arrays. So, seeing the brackets would be helpful.

I would also like to know how to see the contents of an object. All I see in the Dev Tools console is "object".

I can use Chrome, FF or IE to do this. So, a solution in any of these three Dev Tools would be OK.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var myobj = {a: 5, b: "cat", c: ["asdf",1324,353]};

console.dir (myobj);
```

Comment: @phrazzled Your welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add another way to do this:

I was looking at the Developer's Tools in Chrome.

If I set a breakpoint in the code and then use the Sources tab, I can see all sorts of values of variables, objects, arrays, etc.

Just wanted to add this in case someone else looks at this post.